# fetching abstracts from pubmed

Tags: python, biopython

I have problems to get the abstracts from the following query

```
Entrez.email = "anonymous@gmail.com"
esearch_query = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term="cancer AND food", retmode="xml")
esearch_result = Entrez.read(esearch_query)

# Now we need to get all papers from our search using the IDList
for iden in esearch_result['IdList'][-1]:
    pubmed_entry = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=iden, retmode="xml")
    result = Entrez.read(pubmed_entry)
    print result
```

The output is the following (just for one of the entries as an example).

> {u'PubmedArticle': [{u'MedlineCitation':
>   DictElement({u'DateCompleted': {u'Month': '01', u'Day': '10', u'Year':
>   '1976'}, u'OtherID': [], u'DateRevised': {u'Month': '03', u'Day':
>   '22', u'Year': '2017'}, u'MeshHeadingList': [{u'QualifierName': [],
>   u'DescriptorName': StringElement('Binding Sites', attributes={u'UI':
>   u'D001665', u'MajorTopicYN': u'N'})}, {u'QualifierName':
>   [StringElement('blood', attributes={u'UI': u'Q000097',
>   u'MajorTopicYN': u'N'})], u'DescriptorName': StringElement('Cobalt',
>   attributes={u'UI': u'D003035', u'MajorTopicYN': u'N'})},
>   {u'QualifierName': [], u'DescriptorName': StringElement('Hemoglobins',
>   attributes={u'UI': u'D006454', u'MajorTopicYN': u'Y'})},
>   {u'QualifierName': [], u'DescriptorName': StringElement('Humans',
>   attributes={u'UI': u'D006801', u'MajorTopicYN': u'N'})},
>   {u'QualifierName': [], u'DescriptorName': StringElement('Hydrogen-Ion
>   Concentration', attributes={u'UI': u'D006863', u'MajorTopicYN':
>   u'N'})}, {u'QualifierName': [StringElement('blood', attributes={u'UI':
>   u'Q000097', u'MajorTopicYN': u'N'})], u'DescriptorName':
>   StringElement('Iron', attributes={u'UI': u'D007501', u'MajorTopicYN':
>   u'N'})}, {u'QualifierName': [], u'DescriptorName':
>   StringElement('Ligands', attributes={u'UI': u'D008024',
>   u'MajorTopicYN': u'N'})}, {u'QualifierName': [], u'DescriptorName':
>   StringElement('Mathematics', attributes={u'UI': u'D008433',
>   u'MajorTopicYN': u'N'})}, {u'QualifierName': [StringElement('blood',
>   attributes={u'UI': u'Q000097', u'MajorTopicYN': u'Y'})],
>   u'DescriptorName': StringElement('Oxygen', attributes={u'UI':
>   u'D010100', u'MajorTopicYN': u'N'})}, {u'QualifierName': [],
>   u'DescriptorName': StringElement('Oxyhemoglobins', attributes={u'UI':
>   u'D010108', u'MajorTopicYN': u'N'})}, {u'QualifierName': [],
>   u'DescriptorName': StringElement('Protein Binding', attributes={u'UI':
>   u'D011485', u'MajorTopicYN': u'N'})}, {u'QualifierName': [],
>   u'DescriptorName': StringElement('Spectrum Analysis',
>   attributes={u'UI': u'D013057', u'MajorTopicYN': u'N'})}],
>   u'OtherAbstract': [], u'CitationSubset': ['IM'], u'ChemicalList':
>   [{u'NameOfSubstance': StringElement('Hemoglobins', attributes={u'UI':
>   u'D006454'}), u'RegistryNumber': '0'}, {u'NameOfSubstance':
>   StringElement('Ligands', attributes={u'UI': u'D008024'}),
>   u'RegistryNumber': '0'}, {u'NameOfSubstance':
>   StringElement('Oxyhemoglobins', attributes={u'UI': u'D010108'}),
>   u'RegistryNumber': '0'}, {u'NameOfSubstance': StringElement('Cobalt',
>   attributes={u'UI': u'D003035'}), u'RegistryNumber': '3G0H8C9362'},
>   {u'NameOfSubstance': StringElement('Iron', attributes={u'UI':
>   u'D007501'}), u'RegistryNumber': 'E1UOL152H7'}, {u'NameOfSubstance':
>   StringElement('Oxygen', attributes={u'UI': u'D010100'}),
>   u'RegistryNumber': 'S88TT14065'}], u'KeywordList': [], u'DateCreated':
>   {u'Month': '01', u'Day': '10', u'Year': '1976'},
>   u'SpaceFlightMission': [], u'GeneralNote': [], u'Article':
>   DictElement({u'ArticleDate': [], u'Pagination': {u'MedlinePgn':
>   '1424-31'}, u'AuthorList': ListElement([DictElement({u'LastName':
>   'Chow', u'Initials': 'YW', u'Identifier': [], u'AffiliationInfo': [],
>   u'ForeName': 'Y W'}, attributes={u'ValidYN': u'Y'}),
>   DictElement({u'LastName': 'Pietranico', u'Initials': 'R',
>   u'Identifier': [], u'AffiliationInfo': [], u'ForeName': 'R'},
>   attributes={u'ValidYN': u'Y'}), DictElement({u'LastName': 'Mukerji',
>   u'Initials': 'A', u'Identifier': [], u'AffiliationInfo': [],
>   u'ForeName': 'A'}, attributes={u'ValidYN': u'Y'})],
>   attributes={u'CompleteYN': u'Y'}), u'Language': ['eng'],
>   u'PublicationTypeList': [StringElement('Journal Article',
>   attributes={u'UI': u'D016428'}), StringElement("Research Support, U.S.
>   Gov't, Non-P.H.S.", attributes={u'UI': u'D013486'})], u'Journal':
>   {u'ISSN': StringElement('0006-291X', attributes={u'IssnType':
>   u'Print'}), u'ISOAbbreviation': 'Biochem. Biophys. Res. Commun.',
>   u'JournalIssue': DictElement({u'Volume': '66', u'Issue': '4',
>   u'PubDate': {u'Month': 'Oct', u'Day': '27', u'Year': '1975'}},
>   attributes={u'CitedMedium': u'Print'}), u'Title': 'Biochemical and
>   biophysical research communications'}, u'ArticleTitle': 'Studies of
>   oxygen binding energy to hemoglobin molecule.', u'ELocationID': []},
>   attributes={u'PubModel': u'Print'}), u'PMID': StringElement('6',
>   attributes={u'Version': u'1'}), u'MedlineJournalInfo': {u'MedlineTA':
>   'Biochem Biophys Res Commun', u'Country': 'United States',
>   u'NlmUniqueID': '0372516', u'ISSNLinking': '0006-291X'}},
>   attributes={u'Status': u'MEDLINE', u'Owner': u'NLM'}), u'PubmedData':
>   {u'ArticleIdList': [StringElement('6', attributes={u'IdType':
>   u'pubmed'}), StringElement('0006-291X(75)90518-5',
>   attributes={u'IdType': u'pii'})], u'PublicationStatus': 'ppublish',
>   u'History': [DictElement({u'Month': '10', u'Day': '27', u'Year':
>   '1975'}, attributes={u'PubStatus': u'pubmed'}),
>   DictElement({u'Minute': '1', u'Month': '10', u'Day': '27', u'Hour':
>   '0', u'Year': '1975'}, attributes={u'PubStatus': u'medline'}),
>   DictElement({u'Minute': '0', u'Month': '10', u'Day': '27', u'Hour':
>   '0', u'Year': '1975'}, attributes={u'PubStatus': u'entrez'})]}}],
>   u'PubmedBookArticle': []}

How can i get the abstract ?? The final idea is to have some of the fields (such as title , abstract..) in a sql database.

Thanks,
david

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What may be working against you is that typically there are no abstracts for MEDLINE PubMed records from before 1975 -- your example is right on the cusp in 1975.  I worked with your code and a different query that turned up two article ids, one with an abstract and one without:

```
from Bio import Entrez

Entrez.email = "anonymous@gmail.com"

esearch_query = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term="cancer AND wombats", retmode="xml")
esearch_result = Entrez.read(esearch_query)

for identifier in esearch_result['IdList']:
    pubmed_entry = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=identifier, retmode="xml")
    result = Entrez.read(pubmed_entry)

    article = result['PubmedArticle'][0]['MedlineCitation']['Article']

    if 'Abstract' in article:
        print(article['Abstract']['AbstractText'])
```

**TRUNCATED OUTPUT**

> ['This report catalogues all spontaneous proliferations in macropods,
>   koalas, wombats, and possums and gliders held by the Comparative
>   Pathology Registry at Taronga Zoo. Proliferative lesions were present
>   in 14 macropods, 26 koalas, two wombats and 22 possums and gliders.
>   Most neoplasms recorded in macropods were singular and ....']

Details can be found in the document: [MEDLINE PubMed XML Element Descriptions](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/bsd/licensee/elements_descriptions.html)